# Message Queuing solution for WCF

Tags: wcf, message, message-queue, msmq

We are developing a WCF based data analytic  application  which will receives data from multiple instruments , store it in a database and make it available for data analysis... Since the data flow to the application can be high , we are planning to use a Queuing solution , our initial choice is MSMQ ... Can you please let me know if there are any alternate solutions

Comment: If your database is Sql Server, you should consider using [Service Broker queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345108%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) - they take a bit of setting up, but if you're using them to queue writes to a Sql database, performance is excellent and they are very resilient.

Comment: I need to support SQL Server , SQL Lite and Oracle

Comment: You won't want to use Service Broker Queues, then. There are other Message Queue technologies, I've [heard a lot of good things](http://www.quora.com/NET-1/RabbitMQ-vs-MSMQ-For-NET-Project) about [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) which runs on Erlang, and there are [others](http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/04/Message-Queues). Having used MSMQ in the past I would recommend investigating alternatives. (Sorry about the Quora link..)

Comment: Thanks Stuart for the suggestions

Comment: @stuartd I've had good results with MSMQ over the years.  Can you elaborate on why you'd seek an alternative?

Comment: @DarrenLewis MSMQ is OK if all you want is Send and Receive, and you only use Windows. For cross-platform or performance intensive apps (or when your message size might exceed 4MB) there are [a number of other good messaging systems out there](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/message-queue-shootout.html) - I also found it hard to figure out what was wrong when MSMQ wasn't working as expected.